# insert pdo query issue, multiple inserts in wrong table

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo

Have this process to insert data into two tables and is working just fine, but the problem is if i select 3 images for uploading and query them into db and when i submit my form i see 3 queries insertions in db and has to be one in table tours and 3 insertions with same id from tours: in table `poze_articol` for images path with same id from tours at row (`pid`).. something is wrong here

*Php code:*

```
         <?php
        $servername = "";
        $username = "";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "";
         // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection

        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        if(isset($_POST['addtour']))
        {

       #### START FROM HERE I THINK IS THE PROBLEM ###  
        define ("MAX_SIZE","9000"); 
        function getExtension($str)
        {
                 $i = strrpos($str,".");
                 if (!$i) { return ""; }
                 $l = strlen($str) - $i;
                 $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
                 return $ext;
        }
        $valid_formats = array("jpg", "png", "bmp","jpeg");

            $uploaddir = "../../../img/carousel/"; //image upload directory
            foreach ($_FILES['photos']['name'] as $name => $value)
            {

                $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['photos']['name'][$name]);
                $size=filesize($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name]);
                //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
                  $ext = getExtension($filename);
                  $ext = strtolower($ext);

                 if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
                 {
                   if ($size < (MAX_SIZE*1024))
                   {
                   $image_name=time().$filename;

                   $newname=$uploaddir.$image_name;

                   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name], $newname)) 
                   {

         $sql2  = "INSERT INTO tours (titlu,durata,descriere,pret,ribbon,titlu_slider,desc_slider,descriere_box,titlu_box1,desc_box1,titlu_box2,desc_box2,titlu_box3,desc_box3,titlu_box4,desc_box4) VALUES (
         '".$_POST["oras_caseta"]."',
         '".$_POST["durata_caseta"]."',
         '".$_POST["descriere_caseta"]."',
         '".$_POST["pret_caseta"]."',
         '".$_POST["icon_caseta"]."',
         '".$_POST["titlu_slider"]."',
         '".$_POST["descriere_slider"]."',
         '".$_POST["descriere_overview"]."',
         '".$_POST["titlu_box1"]."',
         '".$_POST["desc_box1"]."',
         '".$_POST["titlu_box2"]."',
         '".$_POST["desc_box2"]."',
         '".$_POST["titlu_box3"]."',
         '".$_POST["desc_box3"]."',
         '".$_POST["titlu_box4"]."',
         '".$_POST["desc_box4"]."')";

        if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
            $last_id = $conn->insert_id;

            echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
          <strong>Bravo!</strong> Ai adaugat cu succes un traseu pe site. 
        </div>';
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
        $sql = "INSERT INTO poze_articol (poza_articol,pid) VALUES ('img/carousel/$image_name','$last_id')";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {} 
             }
          }
       } 
    }
 } 
  $conn->close();
        ?>
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? What's happening right now?

Comment: When i hit submit the corect way is to insert in table `tours` only one query and in table `poze_articol` , one,two,three or how many pictures i select to be inserted with the same id from tour table..but is inserting all with diferent ids..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I well understood you, You want create number of files field in `poze_articol` all of this poze_articol field has id of the tour field...

If it is,

So firstly, All of your database insertion are in foreach loop scope, in other words, the portion of code inside foreach loop will be executed x times that the loop iterate. ( n times he has item on $_FILES['photos']['name'] your case).

To resolve the problem,
I suggere you to firstly create tour field outside foreach !

```
        $sql2  = "INSERT INTO tours (titlu,durata,descriere,pret,ribbon,titlu_slider,desc_slider,descriere_box,titlu_box1,desc_box1,titlu_box2,desc_box2,titlu_box3,desc_box3,titlu_box4,desc_box4) VALUES (
     '".$_POST["oras_caseta"]."',
     '".$_POST["durata_caseta"]."',
     '".$_POST["descriere_caseta"]."',
     '".$_POST["pret_caseta"]."',
     '".$_POST["icon_caseta"]."',
     '".$_POST["titlu_slider"]."',
     '".$_POST["descriere_slider"]."',
     '".$_POST["descriere_overview"]."',
     '".$_POST["titlu_box1"]."',
     '".$_POST["desc_box1"]."',
     '".$_POST["titlu_box2"]."',
     '".$_POST["desc_box2"]."',
     '".$_POST["titlu_box3"]."',
     '".$_POST["desc_box3"]."',
     '".$_POST["titlu_box4"]."',
     '".$_POST["desc_box4"]."')";

    if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
        $last_id = $conn->insert_id;

        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <strong>Bravo!</strong> Ai adaugat cu succes un traseu pe site. 
    </div>';
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
```

Because you want be sure that all file will be save both on local disk and database, You can use [transaction](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) to assure the integrity.

Juste after tour field is created, You can do your loop

```
foreach ($_FILES['photos']['name'] as $name => $value)
        {

            $filename = stripslashes($_FILES['photos']['name'][$name]);
            $size=filesize($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name]);
            //get the extension of the file in a lower case format
              $ext = getExtension($filename);
              $ext = strtolower($ext);

             if(in_array($ext,$valid_formats))
             {
               if ($size < (MAX_SIZE*1024))
               {
               $image_name=time().$filename;

               $newname=$uploaddir.$image_name;

               if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$name], $newname)) {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO poze_articol (poza_articol,pid) VALUES ('img/carousel/$image_name','$last_id')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {} 
         }
      }
   } 
}
```